# Add other dataset to display a combination chart

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, chartfx

```
Chart chart1 = new Chart();  //ChartFX
chart1.DataSourceSettings.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
chart1.Data.Series = 2;
DataSetDataValuesTableAdapters.DataValuesTableAdapter adapter = 
    new DataSetDataValuesTableAdapters.DataValuesTableAdapter();
DataSetDataValuesTableAdapters.DataValuesTableAdapter adapter2 = 
    new DataSetDataValuesTableAdapters.DataValuesTableAdapter();
DataSet dset = new DataSet();
DataTable datos1 = adapter.GetDataCaudal();
DataTable datos2 = adapter2.GetDataByPluvio();

dset.Tables.Add(datos1);
dset.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
dset.Tables.Add(datos2);
dset.Tables[1].TableName = "Table2";
```

I can only display one data series in the [chartFX](http://www.softwarefx.com/sfxNetProducts/ChartFX/features/default.aspx) chart. I need to connect another DataSource to the chart so I can display two series of data combined.

Here's an example of [what I want to get](http://ciese.org/curriculum/weatherproj2/en/popup/graph1a.shtml):

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: What kind of chart are you using?

Comment: I am using chartfx, type bar or line chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have this module so I can't test any code. But it seems you should make a combination chart:
http://community.softwarefx.com/forums/p/8501/19692.aspx

> First you need to create a crosstab to pass the data to this chart so
>   that a series is created for each distinct value in the Product Column
>   (Column Header). Check the programmer's guide on the Cross Tab
>   provider for more details. You can also do this using the Chart FX
>   Wizard.
>
> After the data is setup, all you need to do is set the gallry for each
>   series. You can do this in code or using the property grid at
>   desing-time. In code it's something like:
>
> ```
> chart.AllSeries.Gallery = Gallery.Bar;
>
> chart.Series[2].Gallery = Gallery.Lines; // Third series is the Line
> ```